# CarouselView not working in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like to use CarouselView , I have installed it already (CarouselView.FormsPlugin) and I checked the packeges.config of my project and it is already there :

but still I am getting this error 
 The type or namespace name 'CarouselView' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
how can I fix this problem?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CarouselView.FormsPlugin" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.4.247" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
</packages>

Comment: Did you import the right namespace? Are you using code or XAML?

Comment: Im using Xaml and I have already included the namespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're not using the official CarouselView. In the case of the [CarouselView.FormsPlugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CarouselView.FormsPlugin/), the name is a `CarouselViewControl`.

Try it like this:

```
<controls:CarouselViewControl x:Name="myView">
    <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:CarouselViewControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamlTest"
            xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
             x:Class="XamlTest.MainPage">

    <controls:CarouselView x:Name="myView">
        <controls:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:CarouselView>


</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your code in XAML?

Maybe you forgot to put the assembly / namespace?

If so try to put this in your content page tag:
xmlns:carousel="clr-namespace:CarouselView.Forms.Plugin;assembly=CarouselView.Forms.Plugin"

When you do that you can call the control with :

Comment: You code seems right, try rebuilding / reloading your solution

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the wrong namespace in the XAML inside `<ContentPage>` tag. This is correct:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
```